# Sending JMS message to remote queue in JBoss AS via connection pool

Tags: java, jboss, jms, connection-pooling

I'm trying to send a JMS message from one JBoss AS 5.1 instance to the other. For my test I have them both running on localhost, the client JBoss AS instance with the normal port settings and the server JBoss AS with the setting where all ports are offset by 100.

In an EAR project on the client, I've defined a JMS provider loader in a file called jmstest-service.xml in the root of my EAR with the following content:

**jmstest-service.xml:**

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.jndi.JMSProviderLoader" name="jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=MyJMSProvider">
    <attribute name="ProviderName">MyJMSProvider</attribute>
    <attribute name="ProviderAdapterClass">org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter</attribute>
    <attribute name="FactoryRef">java:/XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="QueueFactoryRef">java:/XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="TopicFactoryRef">java:/XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="Properties">
        java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
        java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
        java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1199
    </attribute>      
</mbean>
```

In a file called jmstest-ds.xml I've put a definition for the connection factory:

**jmstest-ds.xml:**

```
<tx-connection-factory>
    <jndi-name>MyJmsXA</jndi-name>
    <xa-transaction/>
    <rar-name>jms-ra.rar</rar-name>
    <connection-definition>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
    <config-property name="SessionDefaultType" type="java.lang.String">javax.jms.Topic</config-property>
    <config-property name="JmsProviderAdapterJNDI" type="java.lang.String">java:/MyJMSProvider</config-property>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>       
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>      
</tx-connection-factory>
```

When starting up the client JBoss AS instance I see the connection factory being created. So, I've written the following code to sent the JMS message:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory)context.lookup("java:/MyJmsXA");
QueueConnection connect = factory.createQueueConnection();

QueueSession session = connect.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Destination destination = (Destination)getRemoteContext().lookup("/queue/nsQueue");
MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(destination);

ObjectMessage  message = session.createObjectMessage("bla");
sender.send(message);
connect.close();
```

With the getRemoteContext() defined as:

```
InitialContext getRemoteContext() {
    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" );
    env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1199");
    return new InitialContext(env);
}
```

Up till here it basically all works. I get references back from JNDI for the connection pool and for the remote queue. However when I actually try to sent the message it fails with an exception:

```
ERROR [ExceptionUtil] SessionEndpoint[pa-96fhptag-1-8wtzotag-7jdzy7-110j3] send [sa-mdkvptag-1-8wtzotag-7jdzy7-110j3]
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to route Reference[20928781172555777]:RELIABLE to nsQueue
 at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.ServerConnectionEndpoint.sendMessage(ServerConnectionEndpoint.java:757)
 at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.ServerSessionEndpoint.send(ServerSessionEndpoint.java:399)
 at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised.org$jboss$jms$server$endpoint$advised$SessionAdvised$send$aop(SessionAdvised.java:87)
 at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised$send_7280680627620114891.invokeTarget(SessionAdvised$send_7280680627620114891.java)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
 at org.jboss.jms.server.container.SecurityAspect.handleSend(SecurityAspect.java:157)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceAdvice.invoke(PerInstanceAdvice.java:122)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
 at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised.send(SessionAdvised.java)
 at org.jboss.jms.wireformat.SessionSendRequest.serverInvoke(SessionSendRequest.java:95)
 at org.jboss.jms.server.remoting.JMSServerInvocationHandler.invoke(JMSServerInvocationHandler.java:143)
 at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
 at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106)
 at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
 at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
 at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:617)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.DelegateSupport.doInvoke(DelegateSupport.java:189)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.DelegateSupport.doInvoke(DelegateSupport.java:160)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientSessionDelegate.org$jboss$jms$client$delegate$ClientSessionDelegate$send$aop(ClientSessionDelegate.java:499)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientSessionDelegate$send_6145266547759487588.invokeTarget(ClientSessionDelegate$send_6145266547759487588.java)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.container.SessionAspect.handleSend(SessionAspect.java:661)
 at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.jms.client.container.SessionAspect_z_handleSend_1677669648.invoke(SessionAspect_z_handleSend_1677669648.java)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.container.FailoverValveInterceptor.invoke(FailoverValveInterceptor.java:92)
 at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceInterceptor.invoke(PerInstanceInterceptor.java:86)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClosedInterceptor.invoke(ClosedInterceptor.java:170)
 at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceInterceptor.invoke(PerInstanceInterceptor.java:86)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientSessionDelegate.send(ClientSessionDelegate.java)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.container.ProducerAspect.handleSend(ProducerAspect.java:269)
 at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.jms.client.container.ProducerAspect_z_handleSend_1677669648.invoke(ProducerAspect_z_handleSend_1677669648.java)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClosedInterceptor.invoke(ClosedInterceptor.java:170)
 at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceInterceptor.invoke(PerInstanceInterceptor.java:86)
 at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientProducerDelegate.send(ClientProducerDelegate.java)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossMessageProducer.send(JBossMessageProducer.java:164)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossMessageProducer.send(JBossMessageProducer.java:207)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossMessageProducer.send(JBossMessageProducer.java:145)
 at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossMessageProducer.send(JBossMessageProducer.java:136)
 at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsMessageProducer.send(JmsMessageProducer.java:142)
```

At this point I'm more than a little stuck :(

I've tried to debug the JMS a little and where it seems to fail is in `org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.MessagingPostOffice#routeInternal`. This method receives the name of my queue (nsQueue), but some internal structure doesn't contain any reference to that:

```
private boolean routeInternal(MessageReference ref, Condition condition, Transaction tx, boolean fromCluster, Set names) throws Exception {
if (trace) { log.trace(this + " routing " + ref + " with condition '" +
                   condition + "'" + (tx == null ? "" : " transactionally in " + tx) + 
                   " from cluster " + fromCluster); }

  boolean routed = false;

  lock.readLock().acquire();

  try
  {
     List queues = (List)mappings.get(condition);

     if (queues != null) // THIS IS INDEED NULL
```

The routeInternal method thus returns false and the above mentioned exception is being thrown.

If I request the (default) connection factory from the remote server, then everything works. The JMS message is correctly sent and correctly received by the server. However, for performance reasons it's necessary to use a local connection pool.

So, does anyone knows what goes wrong here, or knows of an alternative method to use a connection pool for a remote JMS queue?

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you used java:/XAConnectionFactory in the definition of the provider loader. Even though this name will be given to the remote JNDI initial context, it will still go to your LOCAL JNDI, not the remote JNDI against you think it will be resolved. This is just an oddity of JNDI.

You get that exception since your local post office is trying to find the queue ("nsQueue") and it obviously doesn't know about that. Your local post office is being asked, since the code is using the local connection factory, even when you think it's using the remote one.

Just change the references to /XAConnectionFactory and it should work.

Comment: May be helpful: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/userguide-1.4.0.SP3/html_single/index.html#conf.connectionfactory