# Creating JBoss Connection Pool for JMS queue

Tags: java, jboss, jms, connection-pooling

I am developing a Web Service solution that is hosted inside a JBoss 4.2.3 sever and connects to a JMS queue that is hosted on another server.

So far I am creating a new connection to the JMS queue each time the web service is called, this means that, whenever a new session is opened a new connection to the JMS queue is created.

For example, I use the code below to create the Producer:

```
    InitialContext jmsContext;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    Properties properties;
    Queue queue;

    properties = JMSProperties.getJNDIProperties();

    jmsContext = new InitialContext(properties);

    connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jmsContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    queue = (Queue) jmsContext.lookup(queueName);

    producer = session.createProducer(queue);

    connection.start();
```

I am aware that this implementation is not very efficient and I am thinking about creating a connection pool so that I don't have to create a new connection everytime the web service receives a new request.

How can I configure JBoss so that it will create a connection pool to the JMS queue? Does the ConnectionFactory class automatically creates a connection pool for me? If so how can I configure the pool's size?

Thanks,
Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wiki link should help: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossJMSRA

=======================================================

**Update**: 
Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112165/sending-jms-message-to-remote-queue-in-jboss-as-via-connection-pool) with more information on configuration involved.  I would strongly recommend to compare elapsed time for your existing approach and this one.  The reason being this [interesting](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShouldIcacheJMSconnectionsandJMSsessions) post which suggests that JCA caching does not come into picture for remote connection factories bound to local JNDI.  If that's the case, you could use the approach that Nicholas mentioned.  Basically create and cache JMS connection with decent hooks in place to refresh that connection (when needed).

Comment: Hi, I have changed my code to try to use the JBoss JMSRA connection (below): connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jmsContext.lookup("java:/JmsXA");

But now I am getting the error: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: No such destination: JBossQueue[queue] has it been deployed?
Do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Do you have clustered Jboss environment?  If yes, then I believe you need to do a context lookup in global JNDI by using "/JmsXA" instead of "java:/JmsXA".

Comment: Actually no, I have just one JBoss. Do I have to change anything in the JBoss configuration files to make this work? PS: I am using JBoss Messaging and not JBoss MQ.

Comment: posted update to my answer as it was lot of info for the comment section :-)

Comment: Hi, I've followed you posts and everything worked fine! I've even created my own tx-connection-factory in the jms-ds.xml file, however to do this I needed to comment out the line <security-domain-and-application>JmsXARealm</security-domain-and-application>. Do you think that this can be a security issue?

Comment: Depends.  Did you have any security in place before?  Doesn't look like from the code snippet you have posted.

Comment: No, I didn't create any security before, I was using everything as is. The thing is that if I don't comment out that line, than I get the exception: SecurityException: No Password credentials. Do you think that I should configure my Connection Factory to use security? What would happen if I leave it without this security tag?

Comment: If your JMS provider is currently allowing remote connections to be created without any security - I am not sure how much value add would it be to specify the security realm in this case!

Comment: I agree, I don't think that this security realm will be an issue here. Thanks again for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you only need one connection, since they are thread safe. See this [How to handle a Connection object to remote jms server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545374/how-to-handle-a-connection-object-to-remote-jms-server/6564143#6564143)